# Get boolean distributed by a given discrete probability

Tags: kotlin, probability

I currently have a discrete probability that I calculated earlier. I'm getting it like this, so it's just a straightforward double between 0 and 1, which describes the possibility that a certain event will happen. The higher the level, the lower the probability is for this event to actually take place.

```kotlin
val chanceOfLosingDura = 1/(unbreakingLevel+1)
```

I now need a boolean, and every time my code is called, a new one should be generated. The probability for it to be true should be `chanceOfLosingDura`.

I know how to basically approach this. I could just get a list of 100 booleans, of which `chanceOfLosingDura * 100` will be true, and otherwise false, and then draw a random element of that list. However I'm pretty sure that there's a cleaner way to do this in Kotlin, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to generate a random value between 0 and 1 and check if it's greater than `chanceOfLosingDura`:

```kotlin
val random = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
...
val value = random.nextDouble(1.0) > chanceOfLosingDura
```

It's not 100% accurate, but maybe good enough. When I run it 100000 times for `chanceOfLosingDura == 0.9`, I got 10008 times `true`, i.e probability of `false` was 0.89992

Comment: Yeah I'd do this, but you need to flip the condition to ``random <= chanceOfLosingDura``. I think the OP was talking about ``unbreakingLevel`` in the divisor when they said *the higher the level, the lower the probability is for this event to actually take place* - their example with the 100 booleans is basically treating ``chanceOfLosingDura`` as the probability

Comment: Seems much better than my current solution, will use that. And @cactustictacs was right about the level and the probability stuff, so I just adapted that

Answer (score 1):

To make it more Kotlin-way you may define an extension function for `Random` class:

```kotlin
//Returns a random boolean that is true with probability p (0 = never, 1 = always).
fun Random.nextBoolean(p: Double) = nextDouble() < p
```